# IIS Server on XP Machine with tweaked registry and services

Tags: windows-xp, windows-registry, services, iis

I have been trying for some time now to setup a webapp on my XP machine at home.

Prior to doing this, I had tweaked the registry settings, fiddled with disabling and enabling servies, without recording what I tweaked, which I imagining could be what's causing the problem.

I don't want to "reboot" to factory settings, although I suppose that would be nice to know how to do as well.  I am more interested in finding out what settings could have influenced the behavior, and who I could contact / what information I could send them that would aid in solving the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide more details about the problem you are having.

But more importantly, Windows XP's built in web server is no longer a good option for running any web application.

If you have an app not based on Microsoft technology, get something like XAMPP: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

If you want to run a .Net based up, the best idea is to upgrade to Windows 7.  If that is not an option, get IIS Express: https://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1038

Both are standalone servers, so you don't need to worry about messing with registry settings.